# oracledb invalid number error

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, node-oracledb

I am using oracledb (2.3.0) with node (v8.11.3). I trying to run the following query, that return results in sqlDeveloper

```
select TO_NUMBER(RESULTS) from V_RESULTS where RESULTS>=8 AND RESULTS<=10 AND LAND='AT'
```

When I run it with oracledb:

```
oracledb.getConnection(
        config.db_connection,
        function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }

            connection.execute(query,
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                        return;
                    }

                   console.info(results);
                });

        })
```

I get the following error : **ORA-01722: invalid number**

I am unable to find the source of the error.

Comment: You have possible invalid value for number in RESULTS field.

Comment: What data type is `results`, and what values does it contain? (If it's a string... why??) Does SQL Developer return *all* matching rows, or just the fist page (50 by default I think)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible causes. You may just have strings which do not represent numbers - i.e. that simply cannot be converted to numbers. SQL Developer might be giving you a false sense of security if you're only seeing the first page of results and hasn't reached one that cannot be converted yet (possibly even with the filter you are using).

Given that discrepancy in client behaviour, though, it's also likely that you have non-integer values and it's confused about the decimal, with the NLS setting being used by SQL Developer differing from the one Node is picking up from your locale. You can demonstrate the same issue by adjusting that value:

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

with t (n) as (
            select '1' from dual
  union all select '1.5' from dual
)
select n, to_number(n)
from t;

N   TO_NUMBER(N)
--- ------------
1              1
1.5          1.5

alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.';

with t (n) as (
            select '1' from dual
  union all select '1.5' from dual
)
select n, to_number(n)
from t;

Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

If that is what is happening you can change your locale or explicitly set your NLS environment up, or you can specify which decimal separator to use by supplying the format model:

```
with t (n) as (
            select '1' from dual
  union all select '1.5' from dual
)
select n, to_number(n, '999.999')
from t;

N   TO_NUMBER(N,'999.999')
--- ----------------------
1                        1
1.5                    1,5
```

which requires some knowledge of the number of leading and trailing digits to allow.

You can also override `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` as part of the `to_number()` call, but only if you're supply a format anyway - so that just lets you use `D` instead of a period or comma, which isn't terribly useful here.

[According to this](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md), you can just override it at session level anyway, something like:

```
        connection.execute(
            "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'",
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                    return;
                }

               console.info(results);
            });
```

Comment: select * from V_RESULTS where TO_NUMBER(RESULTS, '999.999')>=TO_NUMBER(8, '999.999') AND TO_NUMBER(RESULTS, '999.999')<=TO_NUMBER(10, '999.999') AND LAND='AT'

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precise answer.

Comment: You don't really need the format model for the filter as 8 and 10 are both integers, but it doesn't hurt to be consistent *8-)

Comment: Executing ALTER SESSION is a 'round-trip' between Node.js and Oracle Database, which can impact ultimate scalability.  If you don't want to modify your TO_NUMBER calls, instead set the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS environment variable (and also set NLS_LANG), see the documentation at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#fetchasstringhandling

Answer (score 0):

Error in where Section you compare char type date by number. change where clause to this:

```
select TO_NUMBER(RESULTS) from V_RESULTS where TO_NUMBER(RESULTS)>=8 AND TO_NUMBER(RESULTS) <=10 AND LAND='AT' where RESULTS>=8 AND RESULTS<=10 AND LAND='AT'.
```

if still command has error you have data that can't be cast to number.

Comment: what is your column data type?

Comment: my colum is of type VARCHAR. I got the right answer from Alex Poole